# Rails - rake test fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, db2, rake, jruby

Using the following statement:

```
rails generate scaffold Product title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal
```

and editing a little bit the generated migration I've got the following migration:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :image_url
      t.decimal :price, precision: 8, scale: 2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

After that, I have run successfully the following command:

```
rake db:migrate
```

and connect to my database and check that truly the table have been created. Then, I run

```
rake test
```

and got a lot of errors, and the source of the issue I believe, is that the rails is not able to found the "products" table:

```
 1) Error:
test_should_create_product(ProductsControllerTest):
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Table products does not exist
    arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java:115:in `columns'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.2.7/lib/arjdbc/db2/adapter.rb:514:in `columns'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:660:in `column_names'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:651:in `timestamp_column_names'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:585:in `table_rows'
    org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1257:in `each'
    org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:718:in `map'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:579:in `table_rows'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:494:in `create_fixtures'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:492:in `create_fixtures'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:491:in `create_fixtures'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:168:in `disable_referential_integrity'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:476:in `create_fixtures'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:895:in `load_fixtures'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:849:in `setup_fixtures'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `_run__858744690__setup__1004892786__callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1659:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2086:in `send'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:390:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1659:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2086:in `send'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `run'
```

As far as I've understand, when test are made, my "test" database is erased and migrations of "development" database are apply to it. Because, I am using "IBM DB2 Express 10.1" database I suppose I need to perform some changes on the files responsible for testing.

Could you help me on solving this?

Below, I have displayed more information about the whole situation:

1. Using "IBM DB2 Express" version 10.1
2. Using jRuby 1.7.2
3. Using Rails version 3.2.12
4. Using Ubuntu 10.04 LTC
5. This is how my "database.yml" file looks:

> ```
> development:
>     adapter: jdbc
>     driver: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
>     url: jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/ddevelop
>     host: localhost
>     port: 50000
>     database: ddevelop
>     username: db2inst1
>     password: pass
>
> test:
>     adapter: jdbc
>     driver: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
>     url: jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/dtest
>     host: localhost
>     port: 50000
>     database: dtest
>     username: db2inst1
>     password: pass
> ```

Note: The "dtest" database have been already created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test database has not been updated yet. You need to run `rake db:test:prepare` after `rake db:migration`. You can run it now and try again.

Comment: I get the following line: "Task not supported by 'jdbc'". Could you advice?

Comment: @gotqn, I don't have experience on Rails with JDBC. But the error seems about database adapter. Do you have adapter gem installed? Like http://kenai.com/projects/activerecord-jdbc/pages/Home

Comment: Yes and I have no issues when running my server and working with the development database (add records for example or list records). The issue came up on testing.

Comment: Just took a quick look, maybe you need to run `$ jruby script/generate jdbc', check http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2009/10/12/fresh-0-9-2-activerecord-jdbc-adapter-release/

Comment: Actually in the https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter documentation, you can see that this is only for Rails 2. Anyway, you were completely right that there is a issue with my "jdbc" gem. I have not included "gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'" in my gemfile and this fixes the issue. What is left, is maybe someone to answer why I was able to work with the development database without including the gem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nice you fixed it. Your last question is interesting, but who cares if steps are right and result is delivered :) My pleasure to be of little help.